# Each/every part of coconut tree is used by man

Tags: determiners

Which is the better word to use here ?

> **Each/every** part of coconut tree is used by man.

I went through earlier posts regarding each / every on SE, I can distinguish between *each* and *every* in examples given in those posts e.g.

"its better to say *Every apple is red* instead of *each apple is red*"

but I am not able to decide in this sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*Each* generally refers every X in a group of a known or finite quantity, and implies that when used - *each* sort of suggests an enumeration of some kind.

You would make "parts of coconut trees" a known or finite quantity if you were talking about and/or listing each part.

> Each part of the coconut tree used by man; the stems, bark, leaves, etc...

If you aren't talking about the individual parts you can stick with *every*.